# Why is the object not moving on clicking the button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The object is not moving on clicking the button. Why is it so?

```js
function animate() {
  var object = document.getElementById('object').style;
  var x = 100;
  object.left = x + 'px';
}
```

```css
#object {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: Add HTML it's important for this question how you bind event handler.

Comment: Should have provided an HTML code as well, the code snippet is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume that your element with the `object` id is the button, then all you need to do is attach an event listener to it so that the `animate` function is called when you click it.

```
const object = document.getElementById('object');
object.addEventListener('click', animate, false);
```

Now we just need to rewrite your `animate` function so that it moves the element associated with the click.

```
function animate() {
  var x = 100;
  this.style.left = x + 'px';
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/kqbjr1fr/1/)**

If you don't want your button to be that object, add a button to the HTML:

```
<button id="button">Click me</button>
```

then add the event listener to the button:

```
const button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener('click', animate, false);
```

And then revert your `animate` function back to the way it was. Here I've captured the element only in the `object` variable, as it makes more sense with the variable name you're using.

```
function animate() {
  const object = document.getElementById('object');
  var x = 100;
  object.style.left = x + 'px';
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/8ar8cbgh/2/)**

Note: if the browsers with which you're working support template literals the last line of your `animate` function can be:

```
object.style.left = `${x}px`;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not detach style object from DOM element. Also the name of your function conflicts with native [Element.animate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate) function, name your function diffrently.

This should work:

```js
function animateX() {
  var object = document.getElementById('object');
  var x = 100;
  object.style.left = x + 'px';
}
```

```css
#object {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="object" onclick="animateX()"></div>
```

Comment: A global function name doesn't conflict with an `Element` property.

Comment: Can you explain in the answer why detaching the `style` property doesn't work? Why does this work differently from most other properties?

Comment: The `style` property is just an object. Assigning it to a variable will just make a reference to this object, so you can absolutely do that.

Comment: Actually you are right, detaching object from node, is not a problem here. Function name is a problem. Probably because onclick handler is called in context of the node itself, it translates to corresponding DOM element method.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to include the styling at the end of the statement

```js
function animate() {
  var x = 100;
  var object = document.getElementById('object').style.left = x + 'px';
}
```

```css
#object {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: green;
}
```